Can I use Google recaptcha 3 in an iFrame?
I made a react contact form that will be embedded in websites with a script tag. I am wondering if invisible recaptcha can be used in this form, as, for what I know, it tracks user interaction like mouse moves.
So in this case, it would only track the interaction over the iframe and not the rest of the page.
Is it possible to do this?
Thank you
